# How to get AzureAD user principalId in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rm-template

I want to set AzureAD admin for Azure SQL database. To do it I need to set both login (email) and `principalId`.

Instead of passing both email and `principalId` as ARM template input parameters I want to pass user email only. Then inside a template I want to get user `principalId` by email. For managed identity it's possible to do it like this:

```
[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('web-app-name')), '2019-08-01', 'full').identity.principalId]
```

But I can't find how to do the similar for the user.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to use a script to get the id and then pass it as parameter to the ARM template.

You can use for example the AzureAD PowerShell module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0

```
Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq 'jondoe@contoso.com'"
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same user lookup inside ARM template?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not pretty, and it’s still in preview, but [ARM templates now have support for executing scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-deployment-script).